# how to add iframe from different domain

Tags: html, iframe, dns, src

hi i have the following html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>mytitle</title>
<style>
#idiv {
    position: fixed;
    top:1px;
    height:100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:#0C0;
}
#iframe_main {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


</style>

<style>
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 27px 7px #fff6af;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 27px 7px #fff6af;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 27px 7px #fff6af;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    -moz-border-radius:27px;
    -webkit-border-radius:27px;
    border-radius:27px;
    border:1px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:-12px 12px 11px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="idiv">
<input class="myButton" style="left: 10px; width:auto; height:auto; visibility: visible;z-index: -0; width: auto" value="RELOAD PAGE" onclick="window.location.reload()"/>
</div>
<div style="top:100px;height: auto; width:auto;">

<?php
echo "<iframe id= \"iframe_main\" src=\"http://google.com/\"></iframe>";
?>  

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

when i upload this document to my web server, the iframe does not loading google , it wants to load iframe source as relative target, not loading google.com..  What i need to do, if i want to load iframe window from different domain?

thanks

Comment: Why using echo, you pure html page there?

Comment: i will load (later) iframe sources from mysqli database

Answer (score 0):

X-Frame-Options for [google.com](http://google.com)

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://google.com/
```

it means that you cannot call google.com in an iframe, Google is sending an `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` response header.

There are some interesting sources:

- https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will test it, i want to ask, if is there some universal X-Frame-Option to allow any page as iframe source?